# What is the $C_{P}$ (specific heat under constant pressure) for a Fermi gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, fermions, gas

For some reason I can't find $C_{P}$ for Fermi (electron) gas anywhere; there is only $C_{V}$ quoted everywhere.  However, I definitely can (as I think) change temperature and compensate the small increase in pressure

[image]

by increasing the volume (because $p_F\sim V^{-5/3}$).

Comment: As $T\to 0$ the ratio of the specific heats tends towards 1, i.e. $C_P=C_V+\mathcal{O}(T^2)$ (I think that the next term will actually be $\mathcal{O}(T^3)$). If you really want the higher order terms in $T$ too then you will have to use the Sommerfeld expansion and some complicated asymptotic methods.

Comment: (This is for an ideal Fermi gas.)

Comment: but where did you get that there is no $O(T)$?

Comment: If you're happy with just the first order terms then I can dig out a derivation if you'd like!

Comment: yes, thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

This question is a little tricky to answer because the equation of state of the Fermi gas will change depending on the temperature and interactions involved in the gas. Therefore, I will answer this question by generalizing to any non-ideal equation of state:
$$p = \kappa V^{\alpha} T^{\beta}$$
where $\alpha, \beta, \kappa \in \mathbb R$. Let $S (p, V)$ be the entropy of the gas. From the multivariate chain rule, we can see
$$S(p, V) = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right)_V \text{d}p + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_p \text{d}V$$
Furthermore, if we define the index $\gamma$ as $\frac{C_p}{C_V}$, then we can write
$$\gamma = \frac{C_p}{C_V} = \frac{T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_p}{T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V}$$
Notice that
\begin{align*}
\left (\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V&=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right)_V \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V \\
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_p&=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_p \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V &= \beta (\kappa V^{\alpha} T^{\beta - 1}) = \frac{\beta p}{T} \\
\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_T &= -\frac{\beta V}{\alpha T}
\end{align*}
Therefore, going back to $\gamma$ allows us to write
$$\gamma = \frac{C_p}{C_V} = -\frac{V}{\alpha p} \frac{\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V} \right)_p}{\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right)_V}.$$
Furthermore, you can use the Maxwell relation
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_V = -\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p$$
and the equation
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right)_T= \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right)_V + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_p \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_T$$
to solve for the numerator and denominator of $\gamma$. You will soon find that
$$\gamma = \frac{\alpha +\beta}{\alpha (1-\beta)} = \frac{C_p}{C_V}$$
Therefore if you know $C_V$ and the equation of state of the gas, you can find $C_p$.

So as @xzd209 pointed out, in the degenerate limit, $\beta = 0$, so $C_V \approx C_p$.
References:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_gas)
- Blundell Concepts in Thermal Physics
- [Online Physics Olympiad](https://opho.physoly.tech/static/files/opho2022_open_sols.pdf)

Comment: But what are the coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for $T \rightarrow 0$? I assume that in the first order $\beta=0$ but cannot derive it from integral equation for pressure.

Comment: When $T$ is much less than the Fermi temperature, the gas would reach degenerate pressure, so $\alpha = -5/3$ and $\beta = 0$.